# Precedence of properties: system vs. deployment descriptor vs. properties file

Tags: java, spring, configuration

If I have system property which I pass my container (e.g. Tomcat) like the following:

```
-Dmy.property=myValueOne
```

and a property with the same key defined in my web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>my.property</param-name>
    <param-value>myValueTwo</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

... and a property with the same key defined in one of my config*.properties files:

```
my.property=myValueThree
```

Which value will this property have?
`myValueOne`, `myValueTwo` or `myValueThree`?

If you have several properties with the same key, is there a hierarchy which defines which kind of property overwrites which other kind of property?

Comment: I will assume that all 3 of them will have the same value. btw +1 interesting question

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it more clear. Of course, if all three properties had the same value, the result of the property resolution would be hard to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply said all three will be available and you can use SpEL to obtain the value of each.

```
#{systemProperties['my.property']} // myValueOne
#{servletContextInitParams['my.property'] // myValueTwo
```

The properties depend on how you are loading them (a `@PropertySource` or `

However you probably want to know what happens if you use a placeholder and you have the situation you have.

```
<property name="myProperty" value="${my.property}" />
```

Assuming you use the default (and are on Spring 3.1 or up) the following resources are consulted in order, in a web based environment.

1. Property Files
2. ServletConfig Init Params (
3. ServletContext Init Params
4. Jndi
5. System Properties (specified by -D)
6. Environment Properties

So in your case the `${my.property}` will resolve to **myValueThree**. That is if you preserve the defaults. If you specify `local-override="true"` the property files are consulted last and the value would be **myValueTwo**.

Links

- `StandardServletEnvironment` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment.html#customizePropertySources-org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources-)
- `StandardEnvironment` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html#customizePropertySources-org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources-)
- `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

Comment: @MDeinum do you have official resources for that? +1 btw.

Comment: @Eugene added some links to javadoc.